# What does the arrow hit in the end of The Head Hunter?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-head-hunter

In the end of the movie The Head Hunter, what does that arrow hit?
We know it was supposed to carry souls to the afterlife, and it appears that it should have been his daughter's soul.

Does that arrow have anything to do with the death of the man? How on earth did he get decapitated??